# grammar & spell checking in nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mongoose, socket.io

How to check spelling mistakes, grammar & punctuation errors, use of greetings & short keywords and total time to complete each single chat session in socket.io express mongoose chat application ?﻿

Here is my code, I am successful with spell-checker, but not able to check rest of the things which i have mentioned,

// Grammar check for Message to user
        gingerbread(data.message, { /** options to override **/ }, function (err, text, result) {
            if (!err) {
                var grammar_result = {
                    text: text,
                    result: result
                }

```
            // Insert message in Databae
            chats.find({
                'uid': data.uid,
                'aid': data.aid
            }).exec(function (err, userChat) {
                if (userChat.length <= 0) {
                    // first time user chat this condition call
                    var messages_body = {
                        message: data.message,
                        message_details: data.message_detail,
                        grammar: grammar_result,
                        type: data.type
                    };

                    var chatsData = new chats();
                    chatsData.uid = data.uid;
                    chatsData.aid = data.aid;
                    chatsData.cid = data.cid;
                    chatsData.messages = messages_body;
                    chatsData.save(function (err, saveData) {
                        // call function : chatBot
                        botMessage();
                    });
                } else {
                    // already user is chat this condition call
                    if (userChat[0]) {
                        var messages_body = {
                            message: data.message,
                            message_details: data.message_detail,
                            grammar: grammar_result,
                            type: data.type
                        };
                        var fieldsToSet = {
                            $push: {
                                messages: messages_body
                            }
                        };

                        var options = {
                            new: true
                        };
                        chats.findByIdAndUpdate(userChat[0]._id, fieldsToSet, options, function (err, data) {
                            // call function : chatBot
                            botMessage();
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: better take a look at grammar checkings: https://github.com/kdzwinel/Proofreader

Answer (score 0):

Try [textgears-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/textgears-api) It has a sample and development ability to convert and check the grammar of the application.

```
import textgears from 'textgears-api';

const textgearsApi = textgears('YOUR_KEY', {language: 'en-US'});
textgearsApi.checkGrammar('I is a engineer')
    .then((data) => {
        for (const error of data.response.errors) {
            console.log('Error: %s. Suggestions: %s', error.bad, error.better.join(', '));
        }
    })
    .catch((err) => {});
```

Follow the [git repo](https://github.com/textgears/api-node) for more information